# How to make a string dependency token accessible to components?

Tags: angular, angular-universal, angular-dependency-injection

I'm building an Angular app that uses Angular universal for server-side rendering.

I got a string dependency token being passed as a provider in the providers array of `server.ts`

```
providers: [{ provide: 'MODEL', useValue: process.env.API_MODEL }]
```

The value associated with this token, how do I make it accessible to my components?

If I head into my `app.component.ts` and do:

```
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(@Optional() @Inject('MODEL') private model: string) {
        console.log('inside app component', this.model)
    }
}
```

In my terminal, it prints `inside app component DELUXE` which is expected since that's what's stored in the .env file. However, when I check out the console in the browser it says `inside app component null`. Why isn't the value showing up in the browser?

If I get rid of the `@Optional()` decorator I get a `NullInjectionError: No provider for MODEL!` error.

Comment: `process.env` wouldn't be available at runtime as it's a `node` runtime process, not browser based. Are you using a custom webpack config?

Comment: @Drenai no. Is that something I can configure that will allow access to environment variables?

Comment: You can add the provider in your `main.ts` and perhaps move the existing from `server.ts` to `main.server.ts`

Comment: Like here: [`platformBrowserDynamic(providers)`](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MintPlayer.Web/ClientApp/src/main.ts#L47)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save The data to the server end using transfer state. And once you load on the browser you can fetch the data from transfer state.

The server side receives the data and prints it but in order to have  that data on the client  you must store it transfer state. The code shall be like

```
constructor(
    @Optional() @Inject('MODEL') private model: string,
    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private _platformId: Object,) {
}  

ngOnInit(): void {
    if (isPlatformServer(this._platformId)) {
          this.transferState.set(makeStateKey('model'), this.model);
    } else if (isPlatformBrowser(this._platformId)) {
          this.model= this.transferState.get(makeStateKey('model'), null)
    }
  }
```